# Image on the top of a multi-column layout with CSS

Tags: html, css, css-multicolumn-layout

I have a two column layout (using the CSS multi-column layout module) and I'd like to have an image at the top of the second column. It seems like I have to place the image myself so that it's in the place in the text where the break will be.

The problem is I want the columns to be evenly filled as well.

Is there any way to solve this without JavaScript? This uses a div instead of an image but the idea is to place the red block at the top of its column.

```css
.col-2 {
    -webkit-column-count:2;
    -moz-column-count:2;
    column-count:2;
    width:800px;
}

.block {
    width:100%;
    height:100px;
    background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam blandit neque sed eros posuere molestie. Quisque mattis ante ac mauris iaculis semper vehicula nibh condimentum. Pellentesque scelerisque euismod metus a sodales. Praesent dolor nisl, consectetur at tincidunt eu, dapibus at orci. Etiam congue metus id sapien rutrum euismod. Proin porttitor rhoncus hendrerit. Phasellus pellentesque venenatis felis a eleifend. Suspendisse pretium placerat hendrerit. Praesent tempus risus in ligula condimentum egestas. Vivamus vitae nunc massa, luctus egestas lectus. Vivamus at turpis sed nisl molestie vulputate. Vivamus nec tortor et ante consectetur dignissim ac in odio. Cras et nisl non enim congue scelerisque. Curabitur in condimentum eros. Curabitur vehicula augue id neque dignissim vitae venenatis nisi feugiat.

Curabitur tristique ullamcorper neque, ac sodales eros suscipit eu. Nulla pretium accumsan lacus, non fermentum felis lacinia mattis. Sed quis turpis eros. Nullam ut turpis libero. Nam quis magna ac tortor elementum pulvinar. Quisque rutrum eleifend elit, eget consectetur nulla dapibus ac. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Aenean rhoncus commodo tellus, sit amet pulvinar mi vehicula non. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Morbi mollis dignissim felis, et posuere quam molestie nec. Duis sit amet pulvinar dui. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Ut lorem justo, lobortis id imperdiet nec, lobortis varius mauris. Nullam sit amet nulla arcu. Nullam ornare posuere leo vitae rhoncus.

Sed venenatis dui sapien. Praesent sed enim lacus, vitae venenatis metus. Aenean bibendum nibh a risus scelerisque blandit. Maecenas nibh enim, pulvinar in interdum quis, rhoncus ut orci. Vestibulum a ullamcorper ante. Nulla facilisi. Pellentesque placerat ullamcorper diam at mattis. Aliquam posuere suscipit metus sed sollicitudin. Phasellus in quam odio, ac scelerisque purus. Morbi at nunc odio, nec aliquam urna. Proin mi orci, varius vitae dapibus ac, consequat id purus. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Donec a dui lectus, ut congue nunc. Cras diam tortor, auctor in vehicula vitae, egestas eget neque. In nisi odio, laoreet a convallis in, varius at risus.
    <div class="block"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Some source code/live example would help greatly :)

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific on what you're trying to do please?

Comment: I don't think this is possible. There is no concept of "top of a column" in CSS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The CSS3 spec has a "column-break" style, but it has only been implemented in Webkit. It would do exactly what you are looking for, but only in Safari and Chrome sadly.

You would need to have your column breaking element fall within the normal flow of your content, and add the following style:

```
div.block {
  width: 100px; /* this shouldn't be more than your column width */
  height: 100px;
  -webkit-column-break-before: always;
}
```

[Example (View in Safari/Chrome)](http://jsfiddle.net/hellslam/YNyuc/)

http://css-infos.net/property/-webkit-column-break-before

http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-multicol/#column-breaks

Comment: Yeah, I've tried this, the problem is I want to have the columns evenly filled.

Comment: Oh, I missed that line in the OP, sorry. I don't think that's possible without some scripting. It would be nice if you could absolutely position elements AND set text to flow around them, but I haven't heard of a way to do it without JS.

Comment: Yeah, let the browser position the image.
But I think I will accept this as a solution, the user will simple have to position the image the way he/she wants it in the CMS.

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap the two divs in another div and have the `.block` div before the `.col-2` div in your markup.

[Example for you here](http://jsfiddle.net/Kyle_Sevenoaks/L6CzZ/).

Comment: "I'd like to have an image at the top of the second column" - it doesn't look like your demo is trying to do this.

Comment: Hm, I misread. In that case I doubt that this is possible at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you are trying to do (make the div or image span the full with of all the columns) the way to do this with CSS is to specify column-span: all; on the element (img or div) you want to span across the full width. This is currently only supported in Opera however, and only in an internal build (hopefully we will have a public release with it included soon).

Without using column-span you will have to rely on script or move the mark up to be outside of the element you apply column-count on.

Comment: No, this is not what I'm trying to do, I'm trying to position an element at the top of it's column, not make it span multiple columns.